# (JEST/VueJS) Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, windows-10, nuxt.js

I'm using windows10 and when I run Jest on VUEJS project for tests i've got this :

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1086:14)
```

Itried a lot of soltions, but still not working Here is my jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^.+.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
    },
    snapshotSerializers: [
        "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/tests/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|<rootDir>/**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/']
};
```

Comment: What is Babel config? It should be configured properly. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/22.x/getting-started.html#using-babel , especially `modules` part.

Comment: @EstusFlask still getting same errors using this .babelrc: 

{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["env"], "vue"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Was this your Babel config before? If not, what was Babel config? Are you sure that babelrc is really used? The most simple way to check this is to make syntax error in babelrc.

Comment: I tired to add random "(" symbol  to make  syntax error in babelrc but nothing happened! The original  babelrc config was: {
  "presets": ["vue"]
}

Comment: I guess that's the problem that needs to be solved first, your project ignores babelrc and you need to find a way to change Babel config somehow. I don't use Nuxt myself but I guess you can start here, https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#babel , this can explain why babelrc doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @EstusFlask Unfortunately, I didn't figure out.

Comment: Try to rename your .babelrc in babel.config.js